# Angular: add options to select2 from json object + ng-model issue(empty undefined option)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, jquery-select2

I have such a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/K8rSu/
I trying to solve it by using this:

```
$scope.userInfo.opt = {type : $scope.jsonObj[0].value};
```

I don't need to remove `.opt` from `$scope.userInfo.opt` because I have another user info.
Here's plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/CJghQj?p=preview

Comment: I tried to untangle your code and figure out what is going on but frankly you've overcomplicated things with a mix of javascript, angula, and jQuery.  I would decide which technology you want to use and focus on that one.

Comment: I used javascript to store the data and create function to get this data in json format. And used angular to add json object. I want not to use angular but I can't :( Before I used ng-model for <select> and added data by .append() and then appeared empty option with undefined value. I tried to remove all empty options but nothing helped me.

Comment: I can give more explanations

Comment: Here's example what I tried to do http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/3/

Comment: The root of your problem is the code that you are using to create jsonObj but it doesn't seem like you were asking for help with that code.  If you're trying to figure out the issues with the <select> then I'd start by just defining an array of objects in your controller and cut out all of the javascript to create jsonObj that isn't working.

Comment: I will be happy if you help me to create json object in angular controller

Comment: Define it like this jsonObj = [{key: 1, value:'text1'}, {key: 2, value:'text2'},{key: 3, value:'text3'}].  This is very basic stuff ... if you need help with this then I'd recommend that you take a step back and go through one of the many online tutorials.  Trying to learn angular by following online examples and asking questions on forums is not a good approach to learning a new language.